# upgrader_process_complete filter not fired using ajax updates

Tags: hooks, updates

a very specific question about **upgrader_process_complete** filter (but also upgrader_post_install). I must call some functions whenever specific themes/plugins are updated.

The code works perfectly when plugins/themes are updated through the WP update-core.php admin page, while they are not if plugins/themes are updated respectively from plugins/themes list page, through ajax.

Do you have any hint of the reason why? Or how can I hook into the ajax updater process?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's two thing that relates to this concern.

1. The `upgrader_process_complete` action doesn't fire when the updater is running in bulk mode, aka multiple plugin updates.
   ref: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.0/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L826

```php
// @see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.0/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L826
// @line 826 - 841.

if ( ! $options['is_multi'] ) {
   do_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', $this, $options['hook_extra'] );
}
```

2. The `wp_ajax_update_plugin` function, which is responsible for handing the ajax request performs the each plugin upgrade in bulk mode.
   ref: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.0/src/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php#L4547

```php
// @see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.0/src/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php#L4547
// Line 4545 - 4547.

$skin     = new WP_Ajax_Upgrader_Skin();
$upgrader = new Plugin_Upgrader( $skin );
$result   = $upgrader->bulk_upgrade( array( $plugin ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was missing the wp_ajax_update_plugin() function. However it wasn't the real culprit.

I'm gonna close the question with a self-answer. Thanks again anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Having explored the whole WP codex, I was missing a major point above all the rest: hooks priorities!

`upgrader_process_complete`, `upgrader_post_install`, (etc) hooks must be registered through an hook called also through WP ajax operations (eg. `admin_init`).

I was mistakenly registering those filters on "admin_menu".
Everything solved then!